# Moderncv: address in one single line

Tags: moderncv, addresses

I would like to remove the second argument from the `\address` command in `moderncv`, `classic` style. 
Is there a reasonably easy way to do so?

In other words, I'm trying to remove "Address line 2" from the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[roman]{classic}               
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{title-position}               
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}  % here I want to remove {Address line 2}  
\mobile{mobile phone}
\email{email address}                
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}
 ...........
\end{document}
```

I've tried by simply using `\address{Address line 1}{}` but it leaves a blank line in the output.

Any hint will be most welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you wrote:

> I've tried by simply using `\address{Address line 1}{}` but it leaves a
>   blank line in the output.

That is not true.  It depends on how many informations you want to print in the title.

With style `classic` the title prints the `title-position` and `additional information (optional)` in the same line.

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic} % <=============================================
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{title-position}               
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}  % here I want to remove {Address line 2}  
\mobile{mobile phone}
\phone{phone (optional)} % <============================================
\email{email address} 
\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % <=======================


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image]

As you can see (long red line) There is some empty place above the printed name ...

After reducing the used personal informations (see MWE later) you get the following result:

[image]

Now the name and the title consumes more space than the personal informations on the right. Therefore the empty space is added on the right side ...

This is the MWE for the second screenshot:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic} % <=============================================
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{title-position}               
%\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}  % here I want to remove {Address line 2}  
\address{Address line 1}{}  % <========================================= 
\mobile{mobile phone}
%\phone{phone (optional)} % <============================================
\email{email address} 
%\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % <=======================


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Content}

\end{document}
```

Please see that I moved option `roman` to be a class option (the right place if you use current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The problems came from using an older version of moderncv.